# CSS animation z-index not working right on IOS

Tags: reactjs, sass, css-animations, z-index

I have a simple reactJS module with css animation where an envelope opens, a paper pops up, the paper goes back down, and the envelope closes.

On desktop (chrome, opera and firefox) it works great. On my Samsung (Chrome and Firefox) it works great. On iPadOS it gets wonky.

On Safari, Firefox, and Chrome, the envelope top spreads to the entire width of the screen, and to the top of the screen when it's closing and about to open. On Chrome on ipad, it also puts the envelope top in front of the 'letter' that slides up, when the letter is at the top. I have played with z-index changes, setting translateX values in the animation, and with opacity. I can't seem to figure out what is causing the problem, nor how to fix it.

I have been beating my head against the wall for this stupid little animation for 2 hours. Any ideas where I went wrong?

**.js file**

```
import React from "react";
import './EmailOpen.scss';

const contactEmail = 'email@email.com';

const EmailOpen = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <a href={ contactEmail } >
                <div className="wrapper">
                    <div className="mail">
                        <div className="cover"></div>
                        <div className="letter"><h1>@</h1></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </>
    );
}
 
export default EmailOpen;
```

**.scss file**

```
$envelopeWidth: 90px;
$envelopeHeight: calc($envelopeWidth * .6667);
$duration: 4s;
$borderRad: calc(0.0333 * $envelopeWidth);
$halfWidth: calc($envelopeWidth / 2);
$halfHeight: calc($envelopeHeight / 2);
$letterMove: calc(-0.67 * $envelopeHeight);

body {
    background-color: #000;
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    top: calc(2vh);
    left: calc(50% - $halfWidth);
}

.mail {
    background: #aaa;
    position: relative;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: $envelopeWidth;
    height: $envelopeHeight;
    border-bottom-left-radius: $borderRad;
    border-bottom-right-radius: $borderRad;

    &:before {
        content:"";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 5000;
        border-right: $halfWidth solid #fed;
        border-left: $halfWidth solid transparent;
        border-top: $halfHeight solid transparent;
        border-bottom: $halfHeight solid #fed;
        border-bottom-left-radius: $borderRad;
        border-bottom-right-radius: $borderRad;
    }

    &:after {
        content:"";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 4000;
        border-left: $halfWidth solid #cba;
        border-right: $halfWidth solid transparent;
        border-top: $halfHeight solid transparent;
        border-bottom: $halfHeight solid #cba;
        border-bottom-left-radius: $borderRad;
        border-bottom-right-radius: $borderRad;
    }
}

.cover {
    &::before {
        content:"";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 6000;
        transform-origin: top;
        transform: rotateX(0deg);
        animation: open $duration linear infinite;
        opacity: 1;
        border-left: $halfWidth solid transparent;
        border-right: $halfWidth solid transparent;
        border-bottom: $halfHeight solid transparent;
        border-top: $halfHeight solid #a98;
        border-bottom-left-radius: $borderRad;
        border-bottom-right-radius: $borderRad;
    }
}

@keyframes open {
    0%, 5% {
        transform: rotateX(0deg);
        z-index: 6000;
    }
    15%, 85% {
        transform: rotateX(180deg);
        z-index: 0;
    }
    95%, 100% {
        transform: rotateX(0deg);
        z-index: 6000;
    }
}

.letter {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background: #eee;
    left: calc($envelopeWidth * 0.05);
    width: calc($envelopeWidth * 0.9);
    height: calc($envelopeHeight * 0.95);
    border-radius: $borderRad;
    animation: letter $duration linear infinite;
    z-index: 2000;

    h1 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        color: green;
    }
    
    @keyframes letter {
        0%, 15% {
            transform: translateY(0);
        }
        25%, 75%  {
            transform: translateY($letterMove);
        }
        85%, 100% {
            transform: translateY(0);
        }
    }
}
```